# Difference between using in and up north

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrasal-verbs

Difference between using in and up:
**I live in London, but my relatives live up north, in Manchester**
This sentence can also be written as:
**I live in London, but my relatives live in north, in Manchester**
Is using in here instead of up grammatically correct?
It sounds like when one use up north we are also giving extra information that north is up side, which may be redundant

Comment: This wouldn't make an answer on its own, but some of these 'directions' are idiomatic. In the UK, up north & down south; we don't really have similar 'directions' for east or west. I've heard the US use out west, back east, deep south. idk whether they use others too.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard "in north" but "in *the* north".

*Up north* has a directional deictic aspect. North is relative to the speaker's location. The speaker's location is southerly.

*In the north* has a regional aspect. The speaker's location is not relevant.

Comment: The Bangles' song where they sing about going 'down to Liverpool' always sounded odd to me.

Comment: Could someone in Birmingham say "I'm going down to Liverpool"?

Comment: I doubt it, because Liverpool is further north than Birmingham.

Comment: I was thinking of the seaside use of "down".  Went down to the sea, went down the shore (i.e. from further inland).

Comment: Most of Liverpool is not by the sea.

Comment: But some of it is by the sea. It could be they said they were going down to Liverpool back in the Victorian era when the train line first connected Birmingham and Liverpool.  I listened to the Bangles lyrics and it sounds as if they're quoting what someone has said, someone who has UB40 under their arm.

Comment: @TimR - a UB40 is an unemployment benefit form [as well as a band named after the same, from Birmingham.] The song is by Kimberley Rew [Katrina & the Waves] who grew up in Bristol & Cambridge… from where I'd still think of Liverpool as 'up'. Let's just call it artistic license;)

Comment: Before I fall back upon the comfy cushion of the "artistic license" theory, I'd  want to find out if people from Birmingham say "down to Liverpool".  Birmingham sits on a plateau, doesn't it? Kimberley Rew might be on the money.

Comment: These usages aren't as logical as you seem to think, TimR. From London I might go down to Dover, Brighton, or Cornwall, even though the journey will involve ascending and descending multiple times.

Comment: I honestly don't know how Birmingham got into this thread. UB40 were Birmingham-based, but they have literally nothing to do with the song. Britain is overall too hilly for anyone to really know which town might be higher than another. It isn't really a metric we use, other than for nearby locations, or obviously 'high' bits. I grew up in a city [Leeds] where everybody goes 'down' to the town centre… whether because of tradition or because the town centre is actually the lowest part of the city, it's uphill any way you leave.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. - people in Bristol go 'down the town'; I don't know whether that is helped by the rhyme. When I worked in south Bristol, colleagues said 'Hey, Mike, you live up Redland don't you?'. Redland is a suburb of north Bristol, and if you think that the river divides London north/south, you ought to see Bristol.

Comment: @DoneWithThis.  I'm only holding out Birmingham as a potential explanation (because of the possible  UB40 band allusion in the song) so I would like to find out whether people in Birmingham say "down to Liverpool".  Michael Harvey's original comment made me curious about the phrase in the song. Just following a possible "lead".

Comment: There is no reference to the band in the song. It's an unemployment form, as already mentioned… which fits the 'doing nothing' vibe.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. It could still be an indirect allusion.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  "There are only eight days out of the 365 that flats did not go **down to Liverpool** ... I mean from Runcorn to Liverpool..."   In that case  the river is probably the explanation. Liverpool is downriver.
 https://www.google.com/books/edition/Proceedings_of_the_Committee_of_the_Hous/k4BPAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22down+to+Liverpool%22&pg=PA592&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: More on the possible railway connection to "down to Liverpool": 
 https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Liverpool_and_Manchester_Railway/0cwHEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22down+to+Liverpool%22&pg=PP123&printsec=frontcover